# How to track users' browsers' history in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, adobe-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

Is it possible to track users' browsers' history in GA4? More precisely, which social media or E-commerce platforms do they visit?
Also, I would like to find out whether it's possible to track users' occupations if they are not registered on your website.

Answer (score 0):

You only can collect the info of users visiting **your** website or **your** APP  (for example their interactions); such as page views, button clicks, and purchases. However, it is not possible to track the users’ browser history or their activity on other websites or platforms using GA4. GA4 also does not provide information about users’ occupations unless you have explicitly collected and sent this information to GA4 as a custom user property. Please have a look at [GA4 About events](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9322688?hl=en#zippy=%2Crealtime-report%2Cdebugview-report)